# Can I make gvim not use graphical dialog box for ':set confirm'?

Tags: gvim

I use gvim on windows very frequently. I have in my `.vimrc`:

```
set confirm
```

However, this opens a little dialog box, so I have to use my mouse to quit. In command line vim, I get this:

```
:q
Save changes to "Untitled"?
[Y]es, (N)o, (C)ancel:
```

Is there anyway I can configure gvim to behave this way?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's a good question actually: I had never thought of this before but I added this setting now that I searched for it :-)

From [`:h gui-w32-dialogs`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/gui_w32.html#gui-w32-dialogs):

> 6.1 Dialogs
>
> The dialogs displayed by the "confirm" family (i.e. the 'confirm' option,
>   `:confirm` command and `confirm()` function) are GUI-based rather than the
>   console-based ones used by other versions.  The 'c' flag in 'guioptions'
>   changes this.

So using this in your `.vimrc` will do the trick:

```
set guioptions+=c
```

Comment: I can confirm this works for MacVim/mvim as well.