# Inconsistency with the "Discard All" command

Tags: gvim

I've noticed a strange inconsistency in vim. I have

```
set confirm
```

in my `.vimrc`, but I've noticed that the confirmation varies depending on whether I call `:qa` or hit the *close window* button on gvim. If I call `:qa`, I'm faced with these choices:

```
[Y]es, (N)o, (C)ancel:
```

But when I hit the close window button, I get more options:

```
[Y]es, (N)o, Save (A)ll, (D)iscard All, (C)ancel:
```

Why is this inconsistency there? Can I configure vim so that `:qa` will show me more options?

(For completeness sake, I'm using gvim 8 on windows)

For the purpose of an MVCE, I can recreate this problem with the following `.vimrc`:

```
set confirm
set guioptions+=c
```

Comment: I get the full options with either method. Do you have any other options set that might be messing with confirmation?

Comment: Actually by the looks of it you're getting your dialogs in text based format. Mine are windows. Is there an option for that?

Comment: @Tumbler41 Yes, I'm getting it in text form based off of [this answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/7082/2920).

Comment: I still get the full list for both.

Comment: @Tumbler41 Hmmmm, strange. Does it still give you the full list with my example `.vimrc`? (see edit) And also, which version/OS are you using?

Comment: Yes, same result with your `.vimrc`. I tried with two tabs and two splits. On Windows 7, gVim version 8.0.69.